# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined1

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a Quiz application on React I have a problem with the map function, I use this function to create the response buttons for the problem with the map function levels.
I have an error message
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

```js
import React, {useState, component} from "react";

const QuestionBox = ({question, options, selected}) => {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(options);
  return (
    <div className="questionBox">
      <p className="question">{question}</p>
      {answer.map((text, index) => (
        <button
          key={index}
          className="answerBtn"
          onClick={() => {
            setAnswer([text]);
            selected(text);
          }}
        >
          {text}
        </button>
      ))}

    </div>
  );
};

export default QuestionBox;
```

Comment: May be you passed option as object not an array in your QuestionBox Component

Answer (score 1):

As you using setAnswer to set an object Answer with is also set from option. So I replace the Answer.map with options.map and remove array symbol from setAnswer. Please try this code.

```
import React, {useState, component} from "react";

const QuestionBox = ({question, options, selected}) => {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState({});
  return (
    <div className="questionBox">
      <p className="question">{question}</p>
      {options.map((text, index) => (
        <button
          key={index}
          className="answerBtn"
          onClick={() => {
            setAnswer(text);
            selected(text);
          }}
        >
          {text}
        </button>
      ))}

    </div>
  );
};

export default QuestionBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `options` prop is `undefined` at the time of mount and you're initializing `answer` with it. You can simply add a check condition before the map:

```
return (
  <div className="questionBox">
    <p className="question">{question}</p>
    {answer ? answer.map((text, index) => (
    <button
      key={index}
      className="answerBtn"
      onClick={() => {
        setAnswer([text]);
        selected(text);
      }}
    >
      {text}
    </button>
  )) : null}

  </div>
);
```

Or otherwise initialize it with a default "options" array if the prop doesn't exist.

```
const QuestionBox = ({question, options = ['Default Value'], selected}) => {...
```

or

```
const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(options ? options : ['Default Value']);
```